# Not being able to override Content-type in http.put on angular rc2

Tags: angular, http-put

I'm not sure if this is a bug or something I'm doing wrong in rc2, but the thing is that it wasn't happening in older versions.

I have a http.put request where I need to set Content-type = 'application/json'. As I said, in older versions it was working fine. But when I upgraded angular to the latest rc2 I started to get Unsupported Media Type error.

I inspected the http call in dev tool to check what was being send:

```
Content-Type:text/plain, application/json
```

In older versions I had only 'application/json' and not 'text/plain'. Thus, I assume this is what is causing the error.

What I don't understand is why my headers definition is being appended instead of overridden.

Here is how I'm creating the http.put call.

```js
let opt: RequestOptions
let headers: Headers = new Headers
let searchParams: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams()

headers.set ('Content-type', 'application/json')
opt = new RequestOptions({            
  search: searchParams,
  headers: headers
})
this._http.put('<any put url>', '',opt)
.subscribe(data => console.log(data))
```

Things I've done to double check my suspicions:

- I've manually added 'text/plain' using rc1 version to check if it was
  going to throw an error and the answer was: **Yes, it threw the same
  error.**
- I've created a plunker using https://plnkr.co/edit/Qxw4pd2VnkkWg4iCXwUD?p=preview to simulate my
  scenario. It won't throw an error but It will create the same headers
  I have here.

Is this a bug ?

EDIT

I've opened an issue on angular's repo, and apparently it seems to be a little bug, although what was causing the error in my case was lowercase t in "Content-type", which should be "Content-**T**ype".

It is supposed to bo fixed on a later release.
Issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9452

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem.  I expect this is a bug in RC2.

However, you can get your example to work by making a few changes

1. Set the body to an empty JSON object instead of any empty string
2. Don't override the content-type.

Example:

```
this._http.put('https://httpbin.org/put', {})
.subscribe(data => console.log(data))
```

instead of

```
this._http.put('https://httpbin.org/put', '', headers)
.subscribe(data => console.log(data))
```

Comment: I've edit the post to include the details of the issue opened with angular's team.